# Set width of HTML in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I programmatically set the width of the HTML file i throw into the UIWebView ? My problem is that the UIWebView frame ist set in a TableView cell, so I had to set CGRectMake to fit it in the Cell. But now the size of the content is bigger than the frame... Can I set the width in the UIWebView for the HTML ?

This is the HTML Code:

```
<div id="attachment_16505" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 460px"><img src="http://www.floorballmagazin.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/20130303_schweiz.jpg" alt="Maßgeblich beteiligt - Mathias Hofbauer sprang von der Strafbank und netzte zum 3:1 ein. / Foto: Hans Ulrich Muelchi, Swiss Unihockey" width="460" height="318" class="size-full wp-image-16505 colorbox-16504" /> <p class="wp-caption-text">Maßgeblich beteiligt &#8211; Mathias Hofbauer sprang von der Strafbank und netzte zum 3:1 ein. / Foto: Hans Ulrich Muelchi, Swiss Unihockey</p> </div> <p><em>In der Schweiz kann Wiler sein historisches Ausscheiden aus den Playoffs mit einem versöhnlichen Cupsieg kurieren. Vor über 3.000 Zuschauern besiegen die Berner Grünenmatt mit 3:1. Bei den Damen kann Sandra Dirksen ihren Titelreigen nicht fortsetzen, die Red Ants brachten eine versprechende Führung nicht über die Runden.</em></p> <p>Als Wilers Kapitän Mathias Hofbauer in 56. Spielminute auf die Strafbank wanderte, wurde es nochmal eng für den noch aktuellen Meister. Sein Unterzahlspiel überstand man aber mit Bravour und als Hofbauer wieder zurück aufs Feld durfte, dauerte es gerade mal sechs Sekunden und der WM-Rekordscorer machte mit einem scharfen Schlenzer alles klar.</p> <p>Bei den Damen waren Deutschlands Ex-Nationalspielerin Sandra Dirksen und ihre Red Ants auf dem Weg zum vierten Cupsieg in Folge. Rychenberg führte zu Beginn des Schlussdrittels mit 2:0, brach aber ein und unterlag Chur mit 2:5. &#8220;Wer den Pokal mit nach Hause nehmen will, muss drei Drittel gut spielen und nicht nur zwei&#8221;, bedauert Dirksen.</p> <p>&#8220;Wir hatten zwar den besseren Start, aber am Ende doch nur Silber. Fünfzehn Sekunden vor der 2. Drittelspause haben wir ein abgelenktes, unglückliches Tor kassiert, das war der Knackpunkt leider.&#8221; Dafür sei man umso motivierter für die bevorstehenden Play-Offs. &#8220;Die Atmosphäre bei einem Cup-Finale ist und bleibt einzigartig. Unsere Fans waren toll&#8221;, schätzt Dirksen.</p>
```

This is what happens in the cell:

[image: This is what happens]

Comment: Please post your HTML code and screenshots of what you're seeing if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your own HTML you can do this in it's CSS.

```
body,
.yourClass,
#yourDiv {
  width: 30px;
}
```

If you are not, why not try changing the width of the `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use br tag in the HTML file to adjust your width.

Comment: But the images in the HTML file have their own sizes in the <style> tag.

Comment: no, i am parsing an XML file and get the content which is written in HTML. With NSRegularExpression I could parse out the tags and would have plain text, but with HTML there are more advantages and it is easier than parsing out images and display new lines. I have updated the Question above!